# What is PostgreSQL equivalent of SYSDATE from Oracle?

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I want to perform a query using sysdate like:

```
select up_time from exam where up_time like sysdate
```

which is possible in Oracle.

However, it seems that PostgreSQL doesn't support sysdate. I couldn't find sysdate in postgres documentation. What is the replacement for sysdate in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 111):

`SYSDATE` is an Oracle only function.

The ANSI standard defines `current_date` or `current_timestamp` which **is** supported by Postgres and documented in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

(Btw: Oracle supports `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as well)

You should pay attention to the difference between `current_timestamp`, `statement_timestamp()` and `clock_timestamp()` (which is explained in the manual, see the above link)

---

The part `where up_time like sysdate` does not make *any* sense at all. Neither in Oracle nor in Postgres. If you want to get rows from "today", you need something like:

```
select up_time 
from exam 
where up_time = current_date
```

Note that in Oracle you would probably want `trunc(up_time) = trunc(sysdate)` to get rid of the time part that is always included in Oracle.

Comment: we use "select sysdate from dual" all the time whe running healthchecks on kubernetes pods merely to ensure database connectivity for a pod. Perhaps doing this does not make sense from a database / application perspective, but it does have its use case.

Comment: @gutscdav000 The select with `like sysdate` clause is a nonsense. Not the fact to use `select sysdate from dual;` that all Oracle application on earth uses. To me this is what @a_horse_with_no_name tries to explain.

Comment: @gutscdav000: but `like sysdate` makes no sense. In fact I'd consider code like that a bug. I changed my answer to make it clear to which part I refer

Answer (score 20):

**The following functions are available to obtain the current date and/or time in PostgreSQL**:

```
CURRENT_TIME

CURRENT_DATE

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

*Example*

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIME;
08:05:18.864750+05:30

SELECT CURRENT_DATE;
2020-05-14

SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
2020-05-14 08:04:51.290498+05:30
```

[postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: [Don't use CURRENT_TIME](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_CURRENT_TIME)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for pointing at that page of "donts". Very useful for probably everybody getting to this SO question like me :-)

Answer (score 16):

**NOW()** is the replacement of Oracle Sysdate in Postgres.

Try "***Select now()***", it will give you the system timestamp.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to use **statement_timestamp()**. This give the timestamp when the statement was executed. Whereas `NOW()` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` give the timestamp when the transaction started.

More details in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

Answer (score 0):

Per the Postgres docs there are several functions you can call that return values related to the date/time:

```
CURRENT_DATE
CURRENT_TIME
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
CURRENT_TIME(precision)
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(precision)
LOCALTIME
LOCALTIMESTAMP
LOCALTIME(precision)
LOCALTIMESTAMP(precision)
```

Source of info: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

I have PostgreSQL 15.4 installed and here are some of those commands and their results:

```
select current_date;
-- Result: 2023-11-28

select current_timestamp;
-- Result: 2023-11-28 14:39:04.774712+00

select to_char(current_timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
-- Result: 2023-11-28 14:38:55

SELECT now();
-- Result: 2023-11-28 14:38:33.900983+00
```