# How to remove leading zeroes from day and month values in Oracle, when parsing to string using to_char function?

Tags: oracle, date, select, plsql, format

I want to retrieve a date without the leading zeroes in front of the day and month values in a select statement. If I execute the following query

```
 select to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual;
```

I will get 21.03.2014 as a result. Moreover, if today was, for example, 7th of March, 2014, I would get 07.03.2014. How can I get rid of these leading zeroes?

Comment: I agreed with Doug S on Jan 11 '16 at 4:38: I could only have 'fm' exist once in the string, such as: to_char(sysdate--20,'fmMM.DD.YY'). Otherwise, I received '1.03.14' as the answer shows

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
select   to_char(sysdate,'DD.MM.YY') -- Without Fill Mode
,        to_char(sysdate-20,'fmDD.fmMM.YY')  -- With Fill Mode, 20 days ago
  from dual;
```

Returns

```
21.03.14    | 1.3.14
```

FM  Fill mode.

In a datetime format element of a TO_CHAR function, this modifier suppresses blanks in subsequent character elements (such as MONTH) and suppresses leading zeroes for subsequent number elements (such as MI) in a date format model. Without FM, the result of a character element is always right padded with blanks to a fixed length, and leading zeroes are always returned for a number element. With FM, which suppresses blank padding, the length of the return value may vary.

Comment: FWIW, it also works with PostreSQL ([minus sysdate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16960660/812102)).

Comment: I could only have 'fm' exist once in the string, such as: to_char(sysdate--20,'fmMM.DD.YY'). Otherwise, I received '1.03.14' as the answer shows.

Comment: @DougS That's because `fm` works like a toggle. Notice the description says "suppresses leading zeroes for _subsequent_ elements". If you used `fmMM.DDfm.YY` you would remove zeroes from both the month and day, but not the year (not that the year is likely to ever have leading zeroes, but this might be more relevant if you included the time in the formatting string).

Comment: from what I see, it does not really work like in your example - it rather looks it works like a toggle (like @SnoringFrog) wrote; if you put `fm` before `MM`, the month still display with a leading zero, so I guess the example should be edited.

Comment: can the same be done with  HH: MM associated with the date ?

Comment: "How can we remove leading zeros from single digit months?" Oracle: "fmMM..." Microsoft: "M"

Comment: Note that on Postgres you have to repeat the `fm` prefix for each element, in contrary to Oracle. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`select to_char(to_date('20-oct-2000'),'fmmm/dd/fmrr') from dual`

The above query will remove the leading zeroes from day and month values in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite far from being elegant but it works:

```
select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd')) || '.' || to_number(to_char(sysdate,'mm')) || '.' || to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')) from dual
```

Basically, you would convert to number each part of the date