# How to remove leading zeroes from day and month values in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to remove leading zeroes from results. And I found an answer here [How to remove leading zeroes from day and month values in Oracle, when parsing to a string using a to_char function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552498/how-to-remove-leading-zeroes-from-day-and-month-values-in-oracle-when-parsing-t) , but it does not work for me.

I tried the script as following:

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy'),
        TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 20, 'fmdd-fmmm-yyyy')
   FROM DUAL;
```

I got the result as following:

31.08.2018 | 11-08-2018

Then I tried :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy'),
       TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 20, 'fmMM')
  FROM DUAL;
```

It seems to get the right result :

31.08.2018 | 8

So how can I remove leading zeroes from day and month values in Oracle? What's wrong with me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using format model as `fmdd.mm.yyyy` with only one leading `fm` is enough :

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy') today,
        TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 30, 'fmdd.mm.yyyy') former_day,
        TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2018-08-01','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'fmdd.mm.yyyy') former_day2
   FROM DUAL;

  TODAY     FORMER_DAY  FORMER_DAY2
---------- -----------  -----------
31.08.2018    1.8.2018    1.8.2018
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9835d/1)

Answer (score 0):

For your particular format mask of `dd.mm.yyyy`, you could try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` to remove the leading zeroes from the day and month components:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '0([0-9])\.', '\1.') AS date_field
FROM dual;
```