# Sqlalchemy + psycopg: cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create the following table with Sqlalchemy on Postgres db:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, Float, Integer, String, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()


class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tests"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    create_date = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.sysdate())
```

When running:

```
Test.__table__.create(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1964, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 747, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.FeatureNotSupported: cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression
LINE 5:  create_date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT sysdate,
                                                         ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/application/backend/src/app/db/import_data.py", line 22, in <module>
    Test.__table__.create(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 1149, in create
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(ddl.SchemaGenerator, self, checkfirst=checkfirst)
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3220, in _run_ddl_visitor
    conn._run_ddl_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2427, in _run_ddl_visitor
    visitorcallable(self.dialect, self, **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 670, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 958, in visit_table
    CreateTable(
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 315, in _invoke_with
    return bind.execute(self)
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1414, in execute
    return meth(
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 181, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1526, in _execute_ddl
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1842, in _execute_context
    return self._exec_single_context(
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1983, in _exec_single_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2325, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1964, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/Users/matteo/Documents/DataKind/MyProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 747, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.NotSupportedError: (psycopg2.errors.FeatureNotSupported) cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression
LINE 5:  create_date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT sysdate,
                                                         ^

[SQL:
CREATE TABLE tests (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR,
    create_date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT sysdate,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (name)
)

]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/tw8g)
```

Comment: Are you thinking of [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16960432/5320906)?

Comment: See [Current date/time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

> server_default=func.sysdate()

to

> server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')

or

> server_default=text('LOCALTIMESTAMP')

func.sysdate() - is not a function of **PostgreSQL**.
Read more [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/converting-the-sysdate-function-from-oracle-to-postgresql/).